# Como calcular horas por turno

Tags: oracle, matemática

Tenho uma tabela no oracle com hora de inicio e fim das cirurgias, preciso somar as horas por turno (das 6h00 as 11h59 é manhã, 12h as 17h59 é tarde, 18h as 23h59 é noite e 00 as 5h59 é madrugada).

Cheguei num case gigante, mas pelo tamanho é inviável, também não consegui armazenar as horas para dois ou mais turnos diferentes (ex: quando a cirurgia começa as 10 e termina as 19h [2h para o turno da manhã, 6h para o período da tarde e 1 hora para o período da noite). rs
Esse é um case apenas para inicio as 7h:

```
case when hora = 7 then   
    case when fim = 7 then 0 else
    case when fim = 8 then 1 else
    case when fim = 9 then 2 else
    case when fim = 10 then 3 else
    case when fim = 11 then 4 else 
    case when fim > 12 then 5  END END END END END END 
periodo_manha,
```

---

```
SELECT turno, dia, mes, ano, HORAS_DISPONIVEIS, HORAS_REALIZADAS, 
       TRUNC(((HORAS_REALIZADAS/HORAS_DISPONIVEIS)*100))||'%' OCUPACAO 
FROM(
         SELECT turno, dia, mes, ano, HORAS_DISPONIVEIS, 
                     SUM(HORAS) AS HORAS_REALIZADAS 
         FROM (
               SELECT  dia, mes, ano, turno, COUNT(*) AS HORAS,inicio, fim,
               --Carga horária disponivel por dia dividido em turnos-
               (CASE  WHEN TURNO IN('Madrugada') OR disponibilidade in('24')
                    THEN '6'
           ELSE
          CASE  WHEN TURNO IN('Manhã') AND disponibilidade in('79')
               THEN '30'
           ELSE
           CASE WHEN TURNO IN('Manhã') AND disponibilidade in('74')
                    THEN '30'
           ELSE
                 CASE  WHEN TURNO IN('Tarde') AND disponibilidade in('79')
                    THEN '30'
           ELSE
           CASE  WHEN TURNO IN('Tarde') AND disponibilidade in('74')
              THEN '24'
           ELSE
           CASE  WHEN TURNO IN('Noite') AND disponibilidade in('79')
                    THEN '13'
           ELSE
           CASE  WHEN TURNO IN('Noite') AND disponibilidade in('74')
              THEN '10' 
           END END END END END END END                                       
          ) AS Horas_disponiveis
        FROM( 
        -- Decode para que cada hora defina um turno--
            SELECT DECODE(HORA, '6', 'Manhã', '7', 'Manhã', '8', 'Manhã', '9', 
          'Manhã','10','Manhã','11','Manhã', 
          '12', 'Tarde', '13', 'Tarde','14','Tarde', 
          '15','Tarde','16','Tarde','17','Tarde',          
  '18','Noite','19','Noite','20','Noite','21','Noite','22','Noite','23','Noite',        '0','Madrugada','1','Madrugada','2','Madrugada','3','Madrugada','4','Madrugada','5','Madrugada') turno, 
          inicio, fim, dia, mes, ano, disponibilidade
           FROM(
                                       SELECT inicio, fim,  Hora, dia, mes, ano, disponibilidade
          FROM(
                                                                 --Cada hora da cirurgia jogada numa coluna--
                                                 SELECT inicio, fim,
                case when inicio+0 <= fim then inicio+0 else null end hora0,
                case when inicio+1 <= fim then inicio+1 else null end hora1, 
                case when inicio+2 <= fim then inicio+2 else null end hora2,
                case when inicio+3 <= fim then inicio+3 else null end hora3,
                case when inicio+4 <= fim then inicio+4 else null end hora4,
                case when inicio+5 <= fim then inicio+5 else null end hora5,                       
                                                                case when inicio+6 <= fim then inicio+6 else null end hora6,
                case when inicio+7 <= fim then inicio+7 else null end hora7,
                case when inicio+8 <= fim then inicio+8 else null end hora8,
                case when inicio+9 <= fim then inicio+9 else null end hora9,
                case when inicio+10 <= fim then inicio+10 else null end hora10,
                case when inicio+11 <= fim then inicio+11 else null end hora11,
                      case when inicio+12 <= fim then inicio+12 else null end hora12,
                case when inicio+13 <= fim then inicio+13 else null end hora13,
                case when inicio+14 <= fim then inicio+14 else null end hora14,
                case when inicio+15 <= fim then inicio+15 else null end hora15,
                case when inicio+16 <= fim then inicio+16 else null end hora16,
                case when inicio+17 <= fim then inicio+17 else null end hora17,
                case when inicio+18 <= fim then inicio+18 else null end hora18,
                      case when inicio+19 <= fim then inicio+19 else null end hora19,
                case when inicio+20 <= fim then inicio+20 else null end hora20,
                            case when inicio+21 <= fim then inicio+21 else null end hora21,
                case when inicio+22 <= fim then inicio+22 else null end hora22,
                case when inicio+23 <= fim then inicio+23 else null end hora23,
                case when inicio+24 <= fim then inicio+24 else null end hora24,
                dia,
                mes,
                ano,
                disponibilidade
                  FROM (
                 SELECT to_char(a.dt_inicio_cirurgia,'hh24') inicio, 
                       to_char(a.dt_saida_sal_cir,'hh24') fim, 
                       to_char(a.dt_inicio_cirurgia,'dd') dia,
                       to_char(a.dt_inicio_cirurgia,'mm') mes, 
                       to_char(a.dt_inicio_cirurgia,'rrrr') ano,
                       decode(trim(TO_CHAR(dt_realizacao,'day')),'segunda-feira','79','terça-feira','79', 'quarta-feira', '79', 
                                                                                  'quinta-feira', '79', 'sexta-feira','79','sábado','74', 'domingo', '24') disponibilidade  
--decode para pegar o dia da semana e atribuir o valor de disponibilidade em Horas por dia --
                 FROM cirurgia a where to_char(a.dt_inicio_cirurgia,'mm')= '05'  and 
                                                                                                     to_char(a.dt_inicio_cirurgia,'rrrr')= '2018' )
                     )
                                                                            --unpivot para transformar valores em colunas para linhas--
                UNPIVOT(Hora FOR Horas IN(hora0, hora1, hora2, hora3, hora4, hora5,hora6, hora7,hora8,                                                         
                                                                hora9, hora10, hora11, hora12, hora13, hora14, hora15, hora16, 
                                                                 hora17, hora18, hora19, hora20, hora21, hora22, hora23, hora24)
                          )  
                                )  
      )
      group by turno, inicio, fim, dia, mes, ano, disponibilidade) group by turno, dia, mes, ano, HORAS_DISPONIVEIS) ORDER BY DIA, MES, ANO, TURNO
```

Comment: Qual o tipo da coluna de hora, ou melhor, a estrutura da tabela intera? Existem quais colunas que armazenam inicio e fim? Você precisa saber quantas horas são gastas com cirurgia por turno?

Comment: Eu tenho as colunas inicio, duração e fim. Neste case que passei, o parâmetro hora é o inicio da cirurgia. Exatamente, preciso saber quantas horas são gastas com cirurgia por turno, porque ainda preciso bater com a disponibilidade de equipe e sala para então ter a porcentagem de utilização por turno.

Comment: Ana, se você tem 4 turnos, se uma cirurgia começa as 17 e vai até as 7 horas da manhã, o cirurgião e a equipe que participa da cirurgia não trocam certo? Se o objetivo é saber a disponibilidade da equipe, então se a gente so levar em consideração os inicios da cirurgia daria pra saber quantos colaboradores precisa por turno .. ou realmente precisa saber o tempo gasto com cirurgia por turno?

Comment: Não é simples fazer essa consulta, mas achei bem interessante, vamos esperar outras pessoas ajudarem.

Comment: Desculpe David, não consegui editar meu comentário a tempo rs. minha resposta novamente: O cirurgião e a equipe médica mudam, mesmo que no meio da cirurgia. Aí preciso levar em consideração o início e o fim para dividir as horas

Comment: Consegui! Fiz um select transformando as horas em colunas, uma pivot para transformar em linha e então o count por turno. não foi tão preciso porque não estou constando com os minutos, apenas com as horas, mas deu certo

Comment: Ana, consegue postar sua solução em uma resposta abaixo? Pois, quem mais tiver duvida de como fazer, tera um exemplo de como voce resolveu :)

Comment: excede o máximo de caracteres, como faço?

Comment: Caramba, coloca a parte principal da logica

Comment: Resumi: select count(*), turno FROM(

Select decode(HORA, '06', 'Manhã', ...,'05','Madrugada') turno
FROM(SELECT inicio, fim,  Hora FROM  
(select inicio,case when inicio+0 <= fim then inicio+0 else null end hora0, case when inicio+1 <= fim then inicio+1 else ..., fim, saldo from (select to_char(inicio,'hh24') inicio, to_char(saida,'hh24') fim, to_char(saida,'hh24') - to_char(inicio,'hh24') saldo from cirurgia))
UNPIVOT(Hora FOR DIA IN(hora0,hora1, hora2,...)                         ) )                            )group by turno

Comment: Ana, não em um comentário, coloque no campo de resposta, logo abaixo na página, em "Sua resposta", lá cabe a resposta toda...

Comment: Pessoalmente neste caso eu iria criar uma função genérica que receba por parâmetro o início e fim da cirurgia e retorne quanto tempo levou para cada período em um datetime. Desta forma teria precisão e a consulta ficaria muito mais legível sem um monte de case. Se precisar posso montar um exemplo como resposta.